# WPF Designer can't load VS2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have this error when I try to open a WPF file in the designer even with a new project. Everythings else works perfectly. If I try to compile the project it works nicely as well.

I have tried to uninstall visual studio 2015 and reinstall but nothing changed. On another computer I don't have any problem to open my projects.

[image: WPF error]

**Edit : Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020897/visual-studio-2015-wpf-designer-not-loading-stating-system-argumentexception-an) still not working but not sure about the "Ensure your x86 platform has the correct values to target x86" meaning**

Comment: This helps? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628341/system-argument-exception-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Strang because wpf designer works when for Universal App... But not for C#/WPF

Comment: @Aebiluc I have seen this before.... Are you adding items to a Dictionary in your code somewhere, it looks like you have two Items with the same Key   ….

Comment: This happen on every project even a new project. So no Dictionary. It has to be somethings with VS configuration. I tried to clean it up but it seems that I'm missing somethings...

Comment: The way I have solved this in the past is to comment code out until it fixes it... look in the Constructors and XAML....

Comment: Nothings to comment as it's a blank project. And the code works on another computer.

Comment: `run as administrator` have same behaivor?

Answer (score 0):

It may sound like a silly question, but is Internet Explorer 10 (or later) installed? See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2906882. I had different problems to Microsoft's when I uninstalled IE.

Otherwise, you might try to repair your installation. Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Microsoft Visual Studio and choose Repair.

Comment: Yes IE 10 is installed. I tried once again to uninstall and reinstall everythings (this time in Windows safe mode) but still the same error... I'm running out of idea. Don't want to format my drive